# How to get max_order_value for Payones payment methods?

Tags: magento-1.9, payment-methods, payment-gateway

We want show our users that they reached a certain limit for some payment methods in their basket. That is why I need to know each max order value for these payment methods.

But when I try to use Payones function:

```
$methods = Mage::helper('payone_core/config')->getConfigPayment($store);
```

I get an object with an array full of payment methods. But it is protected and I can not use it. Meanwhile I still do not know if these payment methods are active anyway.

Or is there a totally other way how to retrieve these informations?

Answer (score 0):

This is hopefully the Magento way to get information about Payones Payment methods. You should call `setPaymentRestrictionNoticeMessage()` somewhere in your controller.

```
class YourModule_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract {
    /**
     * Returns array of methods that will not work with current max order value.
     * @return array
     */
    public function getPaymentsWithRestrictions() {
        $quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
        $store = $quote->getStoreId();
        $total = $quote->getBaseGrandTotal();

        /**
         * @var Payone_Core_Model_Config_Payment $model
         */
        $model = Mage::helper('payone_core/config')->getConfigPayment($store);
        $methods = $model->getMethods();

        $restrictedMethods = array();

        foreach ($methods AS $mid => $method) {
            /**
             * @var Payone_Core_Model_Config_Payment_Method $method
             */
            $minTotal = $method->getMinOrderTotal();
            $maxTotal = $method->getMaxOrderTotal();
            $isEnabled = $method->getEnabled();

            if($isEnabled && ($minTotal > $total || $maxTotal < $total)) {
                $restrictedMethods[$mid] = $method;
            }
        }

        return $restrictedMethods;
    }

    /**
     * Sets notification message with information about payment methods
     * that will not work.
     */
    public function setPaymentRestrictionNoticeMessage() {
        $restrictedMethodModels = $this->getPaymentsWithRestrictions();

        $restrictedMethods = array();

        foreach ($restrictedMethodModels AS $methodModel) {
            /**
             * @var Payone_Core_Model_Config_Payment_Method $methodModel
             */
            $restrictedMethods[] = $methodModel->getName();
        }

        Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addNotice(
            Mage::helper('checkout')->__(
                'Your order value is too high for following payment methods: ' . implode(', ', $restrictedMethods)
            )
        );
    }
}
```